# Can I Generate Shipment using GraphQL in magento2?

Tags: magento2, invoice, shipment, graphql

Can i generate **`Shipment/invoice`** using GraphQL in magento 2.4.5 ?

If yes kindly let me know how to generate, any links with brief details also appreciated.

Comment: Magento 2 by default not provide it. For that, need to create custom graphql.

Comment: @RohanHapani, Any reference link for the same?, i mean need to know the params & all if we need to generate shipment using GraphQL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a GraphQL Schema file **`schema.graphqls`** in your module
   directory.

Here is the code.

```
type Mutation {
    createShipment(input: ShipmentInput!): ShipmentOutput
}

input ShipmentInput {
    order_id: Int!
    items: [ShipmentItemInput]
}

input ShipmentItemInput {
    order_item_id: Int!
    qty: Float!
}

type ShipmentOutput {
    shipment: Shipment
}

type Shipment {
    increment_id: String
    trackings: [Tracking]
}

type Tracking {
    track_number: String
    carrier_code: String
}
```

Here's an example of how you can create a resolver class that handles the **`createShipment`** mutation in Magento 2:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class CreateShipmentResolver implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $shipmentRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface $shipmentRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    )
    {
        $this->shipmentRepository = $shipmentRepository;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        $shipmentDatas = [];
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($args['input']['order_id']);
        if (!$order->canShip()) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Order cannot be shipped.'));
        }

        $items = $args['input']['items'];
        $data = [];
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $data[$item['order_item_id']] = $item['qty'];
        }

        $shipment = $this->shipmentRepository->create(
            $order,
            $data,
            __('Shipment Created from GraphQL')
        );

        $this->shipmentRepository->save($shipment);

        $increment_id = $shipment->getIncrementId();
        $trackings = $shipment->getAllTracks();

        $trackingData = array();
        foreach ($trackings as $tracking) {
            $trackingData[] = [
                'track_number' => $tracking->getNumber(),
                'carrier_code' => $tracking->getCarrierCode()
            ];
        }
        
        $shipmentDatas = [
            'increment_id' => $increment_id,
            'trackings' => $trackingData
        ];

        return $shipmentDatas;
    }
}
```

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Hello @MohitPatel, 
Thanks for the details code, i appreciated it, but can you please give me the argument/parameter for this shipment generate like what will we need to pass in GraphQL Client.. sorry i am newbie in GraphQL so not aware of much, I have tried like below but it gives me response null. 
Request:
mutation {
    createShipment(input: {
    order_id: 57987
    items: {
      order_item_id: 1231
      qty: 1
       }
    })
  {
    shipment {
      increment_id
      trackings{
        track_number
        carrier_code
      }
    } 
  }
}